# Customize AWS arn address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to use the `arn` many times, currently it looks like this:

```
arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/FirstName.LastName
```

Is it possible to customize it for something like this ?

```
arn:aws:iam::CompanyName:user/FirstName.LastName
```

So I could use it on others `arn` as well, such as this:

```
arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/my.role
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create account alias.
As your `000000000000` is an account Id.
You can do it using:

```
aws iam create-account-alias --account-alias examplecorp
```

[Here's the link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-account-alias.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this doesn't seem to work with different `arn` besides my account `arn`.